# Rails: split a nested form into partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a nested form which works perfectly fine, however, I'm trying to figure out how to split that nested form into a partial.

original form:

```
  <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

    <%= f.fields_for :achievements, Achievement.new do |ff| %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= ff.label :certification_name, 'Cert Name' %>
      <%= ff.text_field :certification_name %>       
    </div>

    <% end %><!-- fields_for -->

    <%= f.submit 'Save', id: "submit-achievement", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

Here's what I'm trying to do....

```
  <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

    <%= f.fields_for :achievements, Achievement.new do |ff| %>

      <%= render partial: 'achievements/new_certification' %>

    <% end %><!-- fields_for -->

    <%= f.submit 'Save', id: "submit-achievement", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

here's the partial.

```
<div class="field">
  <%= ff.label :certification_name, 'Cert Name' %>
  <%= ff.text_field :certification_name %>       
</div>
```

the problem is that it doesn't know what to do with the 'ff' variable.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `ff' for #<#<Class:0x007fdccd5498c0>:0x007fdcc04894d8>):
```

Comment: You should read up on using locals with partials. You'll need to pass in `ff` as a local.

Comment: thanks, that was it.  had to pass ff as a local.
    <%= render partial: "achievements/new_certification", locals: { ff: ff } %>

Comment: Super! You should toss the accept to @cyzanfar since he actually wrote it up as an answer (if the mood suits you).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by passing a local variable to your partial like so:

```
<%= render partial: 'achievements/new_certification', locals: {ff: ff} %> # not a fan of the naming
```

Then in *achievements/_new_certification.html.erb*

```
<div class="field">
  <%= ff.label :certification_name, 'Cert Name' %>
  <%= ff.text_field :certification_name %>       
</div>
```

[Documentation on partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

Comment: thanks!  appreciate the help.  The nested form is good to go with partials now.